# How tall can Groot grow?

Tags: marvel, groot

We see in the movie and in several comic books that Groot was able to grow larger. This question came about because I was debating with a friend on who was taller, Ant-Man or Groot, because both can grown in size and Ant-Man is limited to 100 feet.

I looked around for quite a while and the best thing I got was 12 feet for Groot. But that can't be if he’s able to grow so tall. So the question is, how tall can Groot become, and if we can't find a good estimate, is it at least or close to 100 feet?

Comment: “the best thing I got was 12 feet from Groot. But that can't be if he’s able to grow so tall.” — Is there a point in the movie where he grows larger than 12 feet tall?

Comment: Marvel Wikia states that he "is" 23 feet tall (presumably meaning that he can grow that high), but is unsourced. Marvel.com simply states that his height is unknown and variable.

Answer (score 6):

#### In terms of your question, Giant-Man at his tallest would be far taller than Groot has ever been seen to grow. However, when Giant-Man was at that size, he found it difficult to do much of anything useful and preferred to stay about 18-30 feet tall, giving him strength and some degree of mobility.

#### Regarding Groot

In his first appearances (in Tales to Astonish) Groot was seen to be over forty feet tall. Note the buildings he stands next to and the truck he is entangling on the ground beneath him.

[image]

It's noted the larger he was, the slower and stiffer he was, possibly due to his increasing mass and the square-cube law that Marvel rarely applied later in its comic depictions.

When we meet him again in his Guardians of the Galaxy appearances, he is much more slender and averages about 18-24 feet during his time with them. This appears to be an ideal fighting weight, making him strong and durable enough to be a threat to the Phalanx warriors, for example.

[image]

His most recent depictions (particularly in the movies and the animations) at 8-15 feet tall.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Vin Diesel confirmed that we would see Full-Sized Groot to fight Hulk somewhere in MCU

> Just be sure... You will see Full-sized Groot and Hulk fight somewhere in MCU.
>   -Vin Diesel

So, it is sure that Groot has a certain height.

Now I researched at marvel.wikia.com and found that Groot's max. Height is 23'

[image: info from http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Groot_(Earth-616)]

Comment: Vin Diesel only says Groot will grow to his full size, but does not specify that size. The Wikia page is unsourced (as indicated in the comment under the question), and as such it's of little worth information-wise.

Comment: Hey! I noticed that a lot of your answers seem to have been downvoted recently. Would you like to join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59579/answer-improvement) to discuss site standards and how to improve your answers (getting some reputation in the process)?

Comment: How can we join in chat?

Comment: @AmanRaizada you can go to the main room, _[The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe)_, or perhaps [the clean-up room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59281/sff-community-cleanup-room).